# Searching , Sorting and Pagination in angularjs 2 using Angular cli

Tags: sorting, angular, pagination, angular-cli

Please suggest me best way of implementing Searching , Sorting and Pagination in angularjs 2 using Angular cli...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular CLI is not for searching sorting and Pagination, it is one great tool to make your workflow as easy as possible with Angular 2.

You can implement in your project the things you requested using components, pipes, for example:

For pagination you can use ng2 pagination:

https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination

For sorting you can use the fuel-ui pipe SortBy:

http://fuelinteractive.github.io/fuel-ui/

Comment: paginaton working but sorting not working please check

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let client of clients | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p } | orderBy : 'clients.organization.businessName' | searchFilter:input.value; let i=index ;">
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td><span class='preview' (click)='preview(client._id)'>{{client.organization.businessName}}</span></td>
        <td>{{client.organization.businessEmail | isEmpty}}</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>{{client.payment.currency}}</td>       
    </tr>

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented all these functionalities recently. Please checkout the below links on github for usages and implementation details:-

[Sort Pipe Github](https://github.com/chhikaradi21/sort-pipe-demo)

[Pagination Github](https://github.com/chhikaradi21/pagination-demo)

[Filter Pipe Github](https://github.com/chhikaradi21/filter-pipe-demo)

[See All Three Demo Here](http://adityachhikara.me/github-demos)